# MariaDB convert column type varchar to int

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

Column has longitude values of form `(+ or -) 36:12:20:0654`. I want to change them to `(+ or -) 36.12200654`. How do I do that?
I tried this command:

```
alter table_name alter column column_name int;
```

but it changes the value to 36 with no sign.

Comment: So you want to convert from `degrees:minutes:seconds` to degress with decimal number? Or just want to get rid of those colons and convert to number?

Comment: I just want to get rid of those colons

Comment: And convert the first color into dot? Anyway, you can't put decimal numbers into field of type `int`.

Comment: what do you mean by first color? I just want to change (+ or -) 36:12:20:0654 to  (+ or -) 36.12200654. How do I do that?

Comment: Okay I converted first colon into dot and then i can see three dots. How do i remove the last two dots. I tried this.... "update table_name set column_name = replace(column_name, ':','.'); but it shows the number as 36.12..20.0654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not proud of the complexity of what I came up with, but it does the trick:

```sql
alter table table_name add column temp double;
update table_name set temp = concat(substr(column_name, 1, position(':' in column_name) - 1), '.', replace(substr(column_name, position(':' in column_name)), ':', ''));
alter table table_name drop column column_name;
alter table table_name change column temp column_name double;
```

UPDATE: based on the new format of the values in the comment, update should look like:

```sql
update table_name set temp = concat(substr(column_name, 1, position(':' in column_name) - 1), '.', replace(replace(substr(column_name, position(':' in column_name)), ':', ''), '.', ''))
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but in the end it turned up filling zero in the column.

Comment: Paste couple real examples of data you have. Do you actually have a space after +/-? If yes, do `update table_name set temp = concat(replace(substr(column_name, 1, position(':' in column_name) - 1), ' ', ''), '.', replace(substr(column_name, position(':' in column_name)), ':', ''));` instead of the update in the answer.

Comment: -99:13:42.1773, 36:25:78.3658 etc are the real examples.

Comment: This is not the same format as in the question. The question didn't have any dots. Updated the answer with a new `UPDATE`

Comment: Make the column `varchar` instead of double. Double cannot hold those zeroes.

Comment: @Santosh, Nice, I didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for negative values. for example -99:23:21.0268 changes to -9.23210268 and some change from -99:23:21.2301 to  0.23212301.... Is there anything i need to change

Comment: I got the exact values but still the datatype is varchar. I want it to be float or double without losing any data. I want the values to be same but the type should be float or double. please help me and this will be my last question